# Downloading a file in Python

Tags: python, urllib2

```
import urllib2, sys

if len(sys.argv) !=3:
              print "Usage: download.py <link> <saveas>"
              sys.exit(1)

site = urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[1])
meta = site.info()
print "Size: ", meta.getheaders("Content-Length")
f = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
f.write(site.read())
f.close()
```

I'm wondering how to display the file name and size before downloading and how to display the download progress of the file. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: am I to assume the code you wrote doesn't work for showing the length? if not, what is the error you're getting? also: to know how long it will take, you obviously need to know the current speed of your connection; that could be difficult.

Answer (score 5):

using  urllib.urlretrieve

```
    import urllib, sys

    def progress_callback(blocks, block_size, total_size):
        #blocks->data downloaded so far (first argument of your callback)
        #block_size -> size of each block
        #total-size -> size of the file
        #implement code to calculate the percentage downloaded e.g
        print "downloaded %f%%" % blocks/float(total_size)

    if len(sys.argv) !=3:
        print "Usage: download.py  "
        sys.exit(1)

    site = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1])
    (file, headers) = urllib.urlretrieve(site, sys.argv[2], progress_callback)
    print headers
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the filename: `print f.name`

To see all the cool things you can do with the file: `dir(f)`

I'm not sure I know what you mean when you say:

```
how to display how long it has before the file is finished downloading
```

If you want to display the time it took for the download, then you might want to take a look at the `timeit` module.

I this is not what you are looking for, then please update the question, so I can try to give you a better answer

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, what I ment to say was how can I track the progress of the download.

Comment: The answer to your updated question will strain the boundaries of my Python prowess, but let me give it a shot: I think you should start your download as one thread, downloading your file to a specific filename. Run a second thread that continually checks the size of the file being saved. This should give you a "downloaded so far: x KB", but I'm not sure if you can use this to output a "downloaded so far: x%"