# how to download in python

Tags: python

I am writing a script which will run on my server. Its purpose is to download the document. If any person hit the particular url he/she should be able to download the document. I am using urllib.urlretrieve but it download document on the server side not on the client. How to download in python at client side?

Comment: Please search.  Please.  It's been asked here a dozen times.  Here are a few hints: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+download

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151841/downloading-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script runs on your server, its purpose is to *serve* a document, not to *download* it (the latter would be the `urllib` solution).

Depending on your needs you can:

- Set up static file serving with e.g. Apache
- Make the script execute on a certain URL (e.g. with mod_wsgi), then the script should set the `Content-Type` (provides document type such as "text/plain") and `Content-Disposition` (provides download filename) headers and send the document data

As your question is not more specific, this answer can't be either.

Answer (score 1):

Set the appropriate `Content-type` header, then send the file contents.

Comment: can you please more elaborate on this?

Comment: Not unless you elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is on your server and your intention is that the user should be able to download this file, couldn't you just serve the url to that resource as a hyperlink in your HTML code. Sorry if I have been obtuse but this seems the most logical step given your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) module.