# How to get wget command info with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Linux (Ubuntu), when I run `wget www.example.com/file.zip -O file.zip` I see a progress bar representing the download progress. As the picture below shows:
[image]

Is there a way in Python to retrieve ALL the information I surrounded in red ? 
I mean that I would love to retrieve into separate Python variables these information:

- The amout of data that is being downloading
- The speed of download
- The remaining time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these information are output to `stderr`, so you need to read them from sys.stderr.
We can use select to read the stderr as the output is changing.
FYI, bellow is a example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import fcntl
import os
import select
import sys

proc = Popen(['wget', 'http://speedtest.london.linode.com/100MB-london.bin'], stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)

while proc.poll() == None:
    fcntl.fcntl(
            proc.stderr.fileno(),
            fcntl.F_SETFL,
            fcntl.fcntl(proc.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK,
            )

    buf = ''
    while proc.poll() == None:
        readx_err = select.select([proc.stderr.fileno()], [], [], 0.1)[0]
        if readx_err:
            chunk = proc.stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
            buf += chunk
            if '\n' in buf and '%' in buf and '.' in buf:
                print (buf.strip().split())
                buf = ''
        else:
            break
proc.wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `wget` in Python using the `urllib` library and a custom function for `reporthook`

```
def reporthook(count_blocks, block_size, total_size):
    global start_time
    if count == 0:
      start_time = time.time()
      return
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    progress_size = int(count_blocks * block_size)
    print "downloaded %f%%" % count_blocks/float(total_size)
    # etc ...

urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
```

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152008/2314737)

Here's a full Python 3 implementation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
['wget', 'http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip', '-O', '/dev/null'],
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

started = False
for line in process.stderr:
    line = line.decode("utf-8", "replace")
    if started:
        print(line.split())
    elif line == os.linesep:
        started = True
```

Now you only have to parse the `line.split()` output and change the `wget` parameter (this is only for testing without saving the downloaded data).

This works on windows with python 3.4:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

wget = os.path.join("C:\\" , "Program Files (x86)", "GnuWin32", "bin", "wget.exe")

process = subprocess.Popen(
    [wget, 'http://speedtest.dal01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip', '-O', 'NUL'],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

started = False
for line in process.stderr:
    line = line.decode("utf-8", "replace")
    if started:
        splited = line.split()
        if len(splited) == 9:
            percentage = splited[6]
            speed = splited[7]
            remaining = splited[8]
            print("Downloaded {} with {} per second and {} left.".format(percentage, speed, remaining), end='\r')
    elif line == os.linesep:
        started = True
```

Comment: Thank you. I run the code without errors (except in `elif line ==` and not `=`). The file is downloaded. However when I add `print(speed)`, `print(remaining)`, `print(percentage)`, nothing is printed. Also I wonder if a `while` loop is not the correct thing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is printed"? (A empty line?)

Comment: Not empty lines, in fact when I run `python download.py` the shell was stopped until the download was complete then I had the hand badck to me to type something if i want. But there were no new lines or empty lines printed. No errors, no warnings.

Comment: On windows wget writes to stderr (I think on unix too). I updated my answer to a working version. Still you have to parse the output of the splitted line.